# Interacting with Gmail inbox using Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I'm working in project where I have to buy a product from some website. I'll get a mail in Gmail I have to click on Received Email (Unread Mail) and interact with the clicked element.

So far I have bought the product and now I'm stuck with the Gmail; I'm not able to open the unread mail and interact with the element when I click 'Unread Mail'.
here is my code

driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
      driver.manage().window().maximize();

```
  JavascriptExecutor exe = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    Integer numberOfFrames = Integer.parseInt(exe.executeScript("return window.length").toString());
    System.out.println("Number of iframes on the page are " + numberOfFrames);



  driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("your mail");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='next']")).click();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  WebElement ele4=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Passwd']"));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//*[@id='Passwd']"))));
  ele4.sendKeys("yourpassword");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='signIn']")).click();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  List<WebElement> unreademeil = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=':3d']"));
  String MyMailer = "StrapUI";
  for(int i=0;i<unreademeil.size();i++)
  {
  if(unreademeil.get(i).isDisplayed()==true)
  {
  if(unreademeil.get(i).getText().equals(MyMailer))
  {
   System.out.println("Yes we have got mail form " + MyMailer);
   break;
  }
  else
  {
              System.out.println("No mail form " + MyMailer);
          }
      }
  }
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=':3d']")).click();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  Thread.sleep(10000);

driver.switchTo().frame(0);

    Thread.sleep(5000);


   ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)", "");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
```

}

Comment: Share your code , so that we can look at it and try to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to interact with the email using Selenium? Unless you're creating automated tests for Google there shouldn't be a reason to do this with Selenium. The reason for this is that every little change Google makes to Gmail has a chance to break your script and requires modification.

Instead I'd recommend using an 'IMAP' library to help you with this. You can login and get the new messages. Using this you can check whatever it is you want to check in your email.

For example: I was creating integration tests for a company I used to work at. When I used a certain feature an email would be send containing a url. To verify this worked correctly I had to get this email and find the url in it. Next I used Selenium to get the url that was in the email and verified if it redirected me where I expected. I collected the email using `imaplib` for `Python`. I logged in, collected my INBOX and fetched the unread messages.

Comment: after buying a product i need to check wheather im getting mails and after i clicked on new mail i have to verify that  product download is present or not